# jQuery Select 2 Divs Up

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm a bit confused on how to properly select a parent item, that is 2 DIV's up.

In other words, my HTML looks like this:

```
 <div>Folder</div>
 <div class="file_info">
   <a href="test.jpg">Test File</a>
 </div>
```

Here's my current jQuery: `$("a[href$='.jpg']").addClass("Image");`

However, I don't want to add the class to the `<a>`, instead, I want to add the class to the 'folder' 2 DIV's above.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
$("a[href$='.jpg']").parent().prev().addClass("Image");
```

First it navigates to the parent element of the selected element and then to the nearest sibling before that element, thus reaching the `div` element you require.

See the documentation on [parent](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) and [prev](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Given jQuery's robustness, there's almost always more than one way to do what you need to do - here are a few methods for selecting a grandfather element:

```
$("a").parent().parent();
```

This does exactly what it sounds like - it selects the parent of your anchor's parent. The *parent* is the element immediately surrounding your target element. In this case, it's a `div` element both times.

```
$("a").parents("div:eq(1)");
```

In this example, notice that we're using the plural *parents*. This looks up all parents for the element, and then returns it as a collection. We then specify which *parents* we'd like to have returned in the collection by providing a specific selection: `div:eq(1)`.

This says we want `div` elements, but specifically those `div` elements that are at position 2 in our resulting collection. By definition, position 2 can only house one element, therefore we return only one element - the grandfather element.

If you're confused by me calling this "position 2" while asking for the `div` that *equals* (`:eq`) `1`, just remember that JavaScript uses a zero-based indexing system, so the first item in a collection is at index 0, and the second is at index 1, and so on.

```
$("a").parents("div").get(1);
```

Another example, similar to the last, which uses `.get`. This too calls upon the `.parents` method to give us all `div` elements. This returns a jQuery object full of `div` elements (assuming your parent-tree is full of `div` elements).

The `.get` method takes an index, corresponding to the element we'd like to retrieve. In this case, we're looking for the second `div` element, which again would be held at index 1 on the collection resulting from the call to `.parents`.

One important thing to note is that this example, unlike those that preceded it, returns an actual `HTMLDivElement`, and not a jQuery object. The difference is that you cannot call the jQuery methods off of an `HTMLDivElement` unless you wrap it again in `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href$='.jpg']").parent().parent().addClass('Image');
```